# Android Paged view indicator like Google Play Application

Tags: android, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

Please provide me example to implement ViewPagerIndicator which have parallaxed effect like Google Play application.

Please see following link to get screen shot:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8kWr56ufFJcRzE1X3RCeXZ6bTQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a "provide me an example" coding service; you need to make an attempt first, and show what didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sur what do you mean about 'view indicator like Google play application'

But you have a great library named ViewPagerIndicator [here](http://viewpagerindicator.com/)

EDIT :
 I not expert with this but it's call android Tabs

[Here](http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/tabs.html) some android information

Hope it's will help you :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i checked your library. I want to have ViewPagerIndicator which have parallaxed effect like Google Play app plication. Do you have other sugesstion?

Comment: Can you provide a screen ?

Comment: Please refer to this link. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8kWr56ufFJcRzE1X3RCeXZ6bTQ/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Google give an example which looks like a little bit play store tab:
http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html

Not sure if it is what you need...

Answer (score 0):

I've found open source to do that. It is PagerSlidingTabStrip. here is source code:
https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip